# (Akka HTTP) When I send an .XLSX file to the user as Array [bytes] then the user get the folder

Tags: java, scala, apache-poi, akka-http

I'm new to akka-http, I encountered a problem: there is a rout that returns a file with a report of a certain format. When an xlsx file is requested, the user receives a folder,

which you can rename this folder in report.xlsx and get a normal working excel file

I send the xlsx file as Array [bytes]
using akka-http 10.0.5

maybe someone faced such a problem:

```java
       path("api" / "reports" / "downloadReport") {
        get {
          parameters('format, 'jobId.as[Long]) { (format, jobId) =>
            uncacheReport(jobId) match {
              case None => complete(ResourceNotFound)
              case Some(report) if format == "excel" =>
                encodeResponse {
                  val reportHtml: String = representerSupport.represent(report, HTMLFormat.Excel)
                  complete(HttpEntity(ContentType(MediaTypes.`application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`), ByteString(reportwriter bytes reportHtml)))
                }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: xlsx files are zip files so maybe your browser is unzipping the xlsx file - maybe you could try using curl or postman so that you can see the HTTP response headers - to check if the content-type is set - it may also be a good idea to set a content-dispostion header with the filename

Comment: @PJFanning thaks a lot! adding the header "Content-Disposition" solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

adding the header "Content-Disposition" solved the problem, thanks @PJFanning

```
encodeResponse {
  val reportHtml: String = representerSupport.represent(report, HTMLFormat.Excel)(user.settings.interfaceSettings)
  val header = RawHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=report.xlsx")
  respondWithHeader(header) {
    complete(HttpEntity(ContentType(MediaTypes.`application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`), reportwriter bytes reportHtml))
  }
}
```

Comment: `Content-Disposition: inline; filename=report.xlsx` is more normal -- https://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/10.1.10/akka/http/scaladsl/model/headers/Content$minusDisposition.html is a class that might help